# Mongoose - Unable to set subdocuments (nested objects) as required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to make the AttendanceSchema's "day" and "attendance" keys required, however without any success.

If I save the fake data whithout both "day" and "attendance" the Mongoose returns an error, as expected. But if I save without one or the other,  Mongoose doesn't return any error and saves it.

Thanks for reading.

---

### Here's my code.

### **ClassSchema.js**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const ClassSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    className: {type: String, required: true},
    classTeacher: {type: String, required: true},
    studentName: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Student', required: true}, //This required works.
    attendance: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Student', required: true} //This required works.
})
const Classroom = mongoose.model("Class", ClassSchema)
export default Classroom
```

### **StudentSchema.js**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const AttendanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    day: {type: String, required:true}, //This required doesn't work.
    attendance: {type: Boolean, required:true} //This required doesn't work.
})

const StudentsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    studentName: String,
    attendance: AttendanceSchema //I set this "attendance" as required, but it didn't change anything, so I left the required out.
})
const Student = mongoose.model("Student", StudentsSchema)
export default Student
```

### **Fake data being saved**

```
const fakeClassroom = {
                className: "How to be a Super-Hero",
                classTeacher: "Spider-Man",
                studentName: "Ant-Man",
                attendance: [
                    /* {day: "monday"}, */ //Commented out to test if it's required
                    {attendance: true} 
                ]
            }
```

### **Saving Controller**

```
exports.postClassroom = (req, res)=>{
   const newClass = new Classroom (req.body)
    newClass.save((err)=>{
        console.log(req.body)
        if(err){
            if (err.name == "ValidationError"){
                return res.status(400).json({message:"Class Name and Class Teacher are required"})
            } else {
                return res.status(500).json({message:"Error creating classroom"})}
        }
        res.status(200).json({message: "Class created successfully"})
    })
}
```

### **Console.log from req.body above**

```
{ className: 'How to be a Super-Hero',
  classTeacher: 'Spider-Man',
  studentName: 'Ant-Man',
  attendance: [ { attendance: true } ] }
```

Comment: Hi it seems that you are not creating an `Attendance` model (only _Student_) in _StudentSchema.js_ perhaps the validation can't be handled?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I created the Attendance's schema, but still there's no validation.